# Is it possible for one player to experience lag and not the other in the same online match?

Tags: ultra-street-fighter-iv

Some times, players complain about lag in an online match (normally when they lose), but I have never had that problem. Is it possible (in a P2P connection)?

Comment: I forgot to say that Street Fighter 4 uses P2P connections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. There are a number of scenarios and factors that could take place to introduce lag, and they're unique to each individual connection.

### Step 1: Computer to Router

- Wireless generally runs slower than Wired connections.
- With many devices connected to Wireless, they all have to "compete" for the same wavelengths in order to send data.
- If you connect to your router via Wifi, a number of things could disrupt this connection: Concrete walls, Electric Cabling, [Microwave Ovens](https://superuser.com/q/637594/107240) etc.

Your best bet is to use a wired connection, straight from your computer to the router - whilst still susceptible to some interference, it's definitely less so.

### Step 2: Router/Modem to ISP

#### Routers

- The quality of your router/modem can have an effect on internet speeds.
- Some routers can better handle multiple connections & constant use compared to others.

#### ISPs

Your Internet Service Provider (ISP) maintains your connection to the outside world. Your router knows how to talk to your ISP, which knows where everything else on the internet is.

You pay them to maintain a 'list' of where everything is on the net (it's a little more complicated than that, but the explanation will do for this purpose), as well as physical infrastructure, like copper/fibre cables and in return, they provide you access to the wider internet.

- Someone on a low-speed internet plan will be restricted in the amount traffic they can send at once, which is a form of 'lag'.

### Step 3: The Internet

- Traffic. Just like cars on the road, the internet has 'busy' times and 'less busy' times. Your game will lag more if everyone else in your neighborhood is streaming Netflix at the same time. However, someone else might not live in your neighborhood, and might have (relatively) little traffic between them and the server.

### Step 4: Destination Server

The game server might be experiencing lag. Too many people connecting at once, or issues with the physical server itself (such as overheating, hard drives dying, or having running processes & programs that have just crashed)

Comment: There are also games where one person's PC *becomes* the server, meaning their lag will be way less than other people's.